# Can I return a single element of a list, as a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have list that I want to return a specific element from, but maintain it as a list, i.e.,:

```
inventory = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
target = 'bbb' #may or may not be set
if target: inventory = inventory[1]
for i in inventory:
    #do something with 'bbb'
```

This obviously pseudo but demonstrates the general flow; fwiw, I've written it this way so that a user can specify a specific entry, or all entries, but not two and not 0. Currently if I specify a `target`, then the `for` loop iterates over each character, rather than the single element.

Comment: This is about lists, not arrays. Lists are Python's analog to arrays, but python also has an `array` module which is different. You can turn anything into a one-element list just by enclosing it with brackets - e.g. `[foo]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly, the following will do it:

```
inventory = [inventory[1]]
```

This creates a single-element list consisting of the first element of `inventory`, and assigns it back to `inventory`. For example:

```
>>> inventory = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>> inventory
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>> inventory = [inventory[1]]
>>> inventory
['bbb']
```

An arguably cleaner way is to use a list comprehension to select elements of `inventory` that match the given criterion:

```
>>> inventory = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>> target = 'bbb'
>>> inventory = [item for item in inventory if (not target) or (item == target)]
>>> inventory
['bbb']
```

Comment: This works for my single element, however, if I do not wish to specify a `target`, this then forces a return of `['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']` for the first iteration of the loop, rather than just `'aaa'`

Comment: @MrDuk: You can still keep the `if` you show in your question. Alternatively, see my second suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a list literal if you're only interested in using this for your iteration:

```
for i in [inventory]:
    ...
```

But I doubt you'll ever need a `for` loop for a singleton iterable.